# Programmatic Transaction in CompletableFuture Chain

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-transactions, completable-future

How can I start a transaction from the first step in a `CompletableFuture` chain, and end it in the last `thenCompose()`? For example:

```
  .thenApply(r -> {
                // Start transaction here
            })
  .thenCompose(r -> {

            })
  .thenCompose(r -> {

            })
  .thenCompose(r -> {
               //end transaction here
            })
  .whenComplete((r, t) -> {

            });
```

Is it possible to do a programmatic transaction? Or I have to go with `PlatformTransactionManager`?

Comment: As far as I know, transactions cannot be passed from thread to thread in Spring, thus they cannot span across multiple threads. Not sure what you are trying to do here but I believe you will have to make sure that transaction handling, as well as queries inside that transaction, are all performed in the same thread. Simplest would be to do that outside of the `CompletableFuture` chain.

Comment: @DidierL Can you please explain in detail by an example